# Error inflate switch button in a tab

Tags: android

I have a problem to inflate a switch button in a tab

my serieb_tab.java is:

```
public class serieb_calendario extends Fragment{

Switch switchButton;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    switchButton = (Switch)getView().findViewById(R.id.serieb_calendar_switch);
    switchButton.setChecked(false);

    switchButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean bChecked) {
            if (bChecked) {
                Log.d("Swirch", "on");
            } else {
                Log.d("Swirch", "on");
            }
        }
    });


    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.sereib_calendario, container, false);
}

}
```

the backtrace is:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: basket.amatoripescara.it.amatoripescarabakset, PID: 19021
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
at basket.amatoripescara.it.amatoripescarabakset.serieb_calendario.onCreateView(serieb_calendario.java:24)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
```

It seems that the problem is to return the view.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`getView()` is null because the view is not created yet and you want to find view in it,so change

```
switchButton = (Switch)getView().findViewById(R.id.serieb_calendar_switch);
```

to

```
View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.sereib_calendario, container, false);

switchButton = (Switch)view.findViewById(R.id.serieb_calendar_switch);
```

and change return statement to

```
return view;
```

Comment: Why I have to di this? 

I wrote another code for a second tab which parse a html page and set a text. The i return the view directly without referencem and worked. Why?

Comment: @AlessandroLosavio Did you read this `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference`,so you need to do this.Anyway edit question with working code.